# Concatenating Queries with if else in PDO Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, prepared-statement

I was trying to convert simple MySQLi Queries to PDO prepared statements
Here is old code

```
if($mode=='')
{
    $query="SELECT * FROM items WHERE 1";
    if($CuisineId != '')
    {
        $query=$query. " AND CuisineId='$CuisineId' ";
    }
    if($CategoryId != '')
    {
        $query=$query. " AND CategoryId='$CategoryId'  ";
    }
    if($DietId != '')
    {
        $query=$query. " AND DietId='$DietId' ";
    }

    $query=$query. " ORDER BY Name ";

    $result= execute_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    echo "<option value=''>Select One</option>";
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value=". $row['Id'] .">" . $row['Name'] . "</option>";
    }
}
```

The new code with prepared statements looks something like this and also working fine

```
if($mode=='')
{
    $query="SELECT * FROM items WHERE 1";
    if($CuisineId != '')
    {
        $query=$query. " AND CuisineId=? ";
    }
    if($CategoryId != '')
    {
        $query=$query. " AND CategoryId=?  ";
    }
    if($DietId != '')
    {
        $query=$query. " AND DietId=? ";
    }

    $query=$query. " ORDER BY Name ";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array($CuisineId,$CategoryId,$DietId));
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo "<option value=''>Select One</option>";
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "<option value=". $row['Id'] .">" . $row['Name'] . "</option>";
    }
}
```

This new code is working fine but here is a worst case in new code.
What if `$CuisineId` or `$CategoryId` or `$DietId` is empty? The Queries will not concatenate and will throw an error on this line

```
$stmt->execute(array($CuisineId,$CategoryId,$DietId));
```

If I start doing IF ELSE will all possibilities, it will make my code too long. Is there any way to counter this issue?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to concatenate with this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM items 
WHERE (? is null or CuisineId = ?)
  and (? is null or CategoryId = ?)
  and (? is null or DietId = ?)
ORDER BY Name
```